# What causes the G1 garbage collector in Java 7 to abort its concurrent-mark phase?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

I've noticed occasional full GC's in my application using the G1 garbage collector, and am trying to figure out why they happen.

The cycle from one region-scan-start to the next is excerpted below.  At 61807.406, a full GC is logged, followed by an entry for concurrent-mark-abort.  What I want to know is why the GC felt the need to do a full, stop-the-world, garbage collection and how I can avoid it.

Note that [this question](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-use/2011-September/000917.html) appears to have been asked before on the OpenJDK mailing list, with no responses.

I've trimmed the details of the young GCs for brevity, but I can post the full chunk somewhere if needed.

```
61805.878: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-start]
61805.882: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-end, 0.0033586]
61805.882: [GC concurrent-mark-start]
61806.133: [GC pause (young), 0.02836202 secs]
   [Eden: 498M(498M)->0B(478M) Survivors: 14M->34M Heap: 3025M(4096M)->2548M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.19 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
61806.426: [GC pause (young), 0.02766222 secs]
   [Eden: 478M(478M)->0B(480M) Survivors: 34M->32M Heap: 3050M(4096M)->2576M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.19 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
61806.717: [GC pause (young), 0.02214895 secs]
   [Eden: 480M(480M)->0B(502M) Survivors: 32M->10M Heap: 3056M(4096M)->2571M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
61807.000: [GC pause (young), 0.01899188 secs]
   [Eden: 502M(502M)->0B(502M) Survivors: 10M->10M Heap: 3074M(4096M)->2573M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
61807.201: [GC pause (young), 0.02619259 secs]
   [Eden: 162M(502M)->0B(500M) Survivors: 10M->12M Heap: 3036M(4096M)->2876M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
61807.283: [GC pause (young), 0.02068515 secs]
   [Eden: 102M(500M)->0B(500M) Survivors: 12M->12M Heap: 3058M(4096M)->2957M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
61807.350: [GC pause (young), 0.01606520 secs]
   [Eden: 52M(500M)->0B(498M) Survivors: 12M->14M Heap: 3020M(4096M)->2969M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
61807.389: [GC pause (young), 0.01573865 secs]
   [Eden: 42M(498M)->0B(500M) Survivors: 14M->12M Heap: 3021M(4096M)->2978M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
61807.406: [Full GC 2978M->2498M(4096M), 4.8896638 secs]
 [Times: user=6.37 sys=0.08, real=4.89 secs] 
61812.296: [GC concurrent-mark-abort]
61812.542: [GC pause (young), 0.01526403 secs]
   [Eden: 512M(500M)->0B(510M) Survivors: 0B->2048K Heap: 3018M(4096M)->2506M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
61812.793: [GC pause (young) (initial-mark), 0.01391544 secs]
   [Eden: 510M(510M)->0B(508M) Survivors: 2048K->4096K Heap: 3016M(4096M)->2508M(4096M)]
 [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
61812.807: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-start]
```

This is using the Java Hotspot 1.7.0_7 release, with the following interesting settings:

```
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-XX:NewSize=512m
-XX:MaxNewSize=512m
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+UnsyncloadClass
-XX:+UseTLAB
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SurvivorRatio=10
-Xloggc:./workspace/gc.log
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGC
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you know about [this reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html). [This page](https://javabeat.net/g1-garbage-collector-in-java-7-0/) is also useful.

Full GC's occur when tenured objects - those that survive collection in the ephemeral (young) generation - fill up the space allocated for them.  When a full GC occurs, any ephemeral marking that was in progress must be aborted.

Decreasing the rate at which the tenured generation fills up requires either adding more heap/RAM or fiddling with the division of available memory between tenured and young spaces.  The parameters `NewSize`, `MaxNewSize` and `NewRatio` are for the latter.  Experiment is the only way to find what will work.

Common wisdom is that shifting the ratio to make the tenured generation bigger decreases the number of full collections.  In many cases this is true, but not always.  There is a condition where many tenured objects are becoming dead shortly after they're tenured.  In other words, they should have been collected in the young area, but their life ended a bit too late for that.  In this case making the young generation bigger allows these objects to be collected there rather than being tenured.  A symptom of this is full collection causing a big decrease in allocated space.

That doesn't seem to be your case: `2978M->2498M`.  Your only out may be to make the heap bigger, buying more memory as needed.  Still, nearly all systems that run a long time will have a full collection once in a while.

Comment: Couple of q's: 'Full GC's occur when tenured objects... fill up the space allocated for them'.  My tenured space should be 3.5g (4g heap - 512m MaxNewSize).  From the young collections just before the full gc, it looks like the amount of data in tenured was 3g.  3.5 > 3, so I would think not full and no GC.  Am I misinterpreting that?

Comment: 'Still, nearly all systems that run a long time will have a full collection once in a while.'  I know this is true with CMS in Java6, although to my mind mainly because of fragmentation. I thought with G1 it would only be the case if the marking threads simply couldn't keep up with garbage production, which with proper tuning should be avoidable.  Any reason you think that with G1 you'd have to occasionally run a full gc?

Comment: G1 uses many regions. Full collections occur when promotion fails: no empty region is available for compaction. The longer a system runs, the better the chance that every region will have at least one live object.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing authoritative. There is a free space for promotion tunable papameter. When regions >50% full total more than allowable, there is nothing else the GC can do! People citing such fragmentation among regions include these: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/Dp7RfmtOWB5JGyYecb8E and http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.cassandra.user/28034. Can't find others I've seen. See also http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/156 about class unloading and http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-status-of-the-implementation-of-the-G1-garbage-collector-for-the-JVM for a problem similar to yours.

Comment: FYI, the same two people are the primary authors of your first, second, and fourth links.  (The second and fourth are posts each made independently, and the first is a conversation between them.)  That's not to discount the validity of their experiences, just to say your sample size is a bit smaller than it appears at first glance.

Comment: You guys do realise that when you specify the young gen GC options like NewRatio you disable the adaptive heuristics in G1 right? With G1 GC you should start with the defaults and then have a very good reason for changing them. See http://www.infoq.com/presentations/java-g1?utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=related_content_link&utm_campaign=relatedContent_articles_clk#downloadPdf